# process.env adding undefined after itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm having a really strange interaction with my env file when trying to use it in a fetch request.

.env:

```
URL = http://localhost:3000/
```

fetch request:

```
fetch(`${process.env.URL}api/data`,{})
```

return:

```
http://localhost:3000/undefinedapi/data
```

I have also tried changing the fetch request to:

```
fetch(`${process.env.URL}/api/data`,{})
```

return:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/data
```

This slightly fixed the url structure but doesn't help the act that for some reason it's adding undefined after the proccessing the env.

Comment: @RahulBeniwal just a copy paste error, fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Robin.

Comment: @RobinBanks I never do downvotes. Please be professional and respect timezone gap. Can you please check if you are overwriting it in file or during process, process.env will never add undefined that's for sure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-scripts all custom variables requires a prefix REACT_APP to be exposed.
Every custom variable without prefix will return undefined.

Try change the `URL` to `REACT_APP_URL` and `process.env.REACT_APP_URL`

Comment: I have tried this to no resolve

Comment: Is your .env file placed in the root folder where package.json is?

Comment: Yes it is. has been there form creation

Comment: Different .env variables working fine? Did you rebuild/restart server for REACT_APP prefix? Do you have dotenv package installed?